# How to get VMware Fusion Ubuntu VM to use host's DNS?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-fusion, osx-el-capitan

I have VMware Fusion Pro 8 running on my OSX El Capitano. I created Ubuntu 14.04 VM and configured network adapter to use Wi-fi bridged networking so my VM gets its own IP.

My company is using local DNS to resolve local names. My question is how can I add this local DNS to my VM?

Some answers to similar questions suggest to add DNS to the /etc/resolv.conf but content of my resolv.conf suggest that I am not supposed to do that:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

What is the proper way to add the DNS in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install `VM Ware Tools` on Ubuntu? It usually solves these issues and makes sure all compatible drivers are installed.

Comment: Yes, I did, but did not solve the problem when network adapter uses W-Fi bridged networking. It only works fine when using NAT mode.